# How to draw and visualize a certain area in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus

I'm given an area in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that is defined as the following:

$$ x = \left(1 + \rho \sin(\frac{\varphi}{2})\right) \cos(\varphi)$$

$$ y = \left(1 + \rho \sin(\frac{\varphi}{2})\right) \sin(\varphi)$$

$$ z =  \rho \cos(\frac{\varphi}{2}) $$

where $\rho \in [-\frac{1}{2}; \frac{1}{2}]$ and $\varphi \in [0;2\pi]$.
I just need to calculate its area, which is cumbersome but easy enough, but is it possible to draw it / have a good intuition what it could look like, which also could help my in the calculation of its area? Is there a general way to go about a problem like this? I already tried inserting some points but I didn't see any pattern at all.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you have in mind, but an easy way to visualize parametric surfaces like this one is to generate a triangulation with a computer.  For example using python you could follow [this](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/trisurf3d_2.html) example using the library matplotlib.

Comment: Do you know spherical coordinates?

Comment: @Mark S. Sure, but I'm not really sure how they would help me out here?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this [website](https://www.geogebra.org/m/BjV7cNwb) to draw the 3D surface (parametric plot)

[image]